# How to string convert to array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, string, collections

I want to convert to this array

$string = "1,[1,2,3],[2,2,4],2,3";
To
Example

```
0 => 1,
1 => [
       0 => 1,
       1 => 2,
       2 => 3
     ],
2 => [
       0 => 2,
       1 => 2,
       2 => 4
     ],
3 => 2,
4 => 3
```

Comment: Try like this ```dd(json_encode($yourArray));```

Comment: `json_decode("[{$string}]")` should do it (or `json_decode("[$string]")` if you want the shortest version).

Comment: Is this your way of serialization?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `json_decode()` :

```
$string = "1,[1,2,3],[2,2,4],2,3";
$array = json_decode("[$string]", true);
print_r($array);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 4
        )

    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
)
```

Above code tested [here](https://rextester.com/WHDDE32334)